# How to calculate difference between 2 time stamps in PERL

Tags: perl

Code to calculate the difference between 2 given time stamps.  `Start_Time="2017-09-19 19:36:12.763"`  `End_Time="2017-09-19 19:36:22.72"`  I want to get the difference between above 2 time stamps also considering the milliseconds.

This is what i tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;
use Date::Parse;
use Date::Format;

$startdat = "2007-11-17 12:51:22";
$stopdate = "2007-11-17 12:52:22";

my ($years, $months, $days, $hours, $mins, $secs) = split /\W+/, $startdat;
my ($yeart, $montht, $dayt, $hourt, $mint, $sect) = split /\W+/, $stopdate;

my $times = timelocal($secs,$mins,$hours,$days,$months,$years);
my $timet = timelocal($sect,$mint,$hourt,$dayt,$montht,$yeart);

$time = $timet - $times;

print $time;
```

But this gives me an error: Can't locate Date/Parse.pm in @INC.

Comment: @abbasp: Also, please consider giving your question a better title.

Comment: @abbasp: I've fixed the formatting of your code for you. It might be worth reading [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @Borodin: I have edited the question whatever OP updated the coding in the comments, unfortunately someone edited the question before I have edited the same. That's the issue. However I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that error message because Date::Parse isn't installed. This module isn't a part of the standard Perl distribution and needs to be installed separately. If you want to use it, then you need to install it.

However.

Although you `use` Date::Parse and Date::Format in your code, you don't actually make use of them. So you can just delete those two lines. Then your code will probably work.

Date::Parse and Date::Format are actually quite dated modules. For date and time work in Perl, I recommend [Time::Piec](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece)e (which is a standard part of the Perl library) or [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) (which needs to be installed).